Why is the line of command random.randint not working properly
Im trying to learn python but somehow the command to generate random numbers is not working.
My code is:
import random

##First try

random_integer =  random.randint ( a: 1, b: 100 )

This is what i get.
  random_integer =  random.randint ( a: 1, b: 100 )
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I am using Visual Studios and i installed some plugs already.
In the problems tag i get "a" is not defined.

The colons are not proper syntax when calling a function. Try random.randint(a=1, b=100) or simply random.randint(1, 100)

You will find this documentation helpful

That isn't valid python syntax. It seems like you've mixed up type hinting and calling a function with keyword arguments. The function you want is defined as
random.randint(a, b)

It can be called using unnamed positional parameters as in
random_integer =  random.randint (1, 100)

where the first parameter is a and the second is b.
Or named keyword parameters where the order doesn't matter
random_integer =  random.randint (a=1, b=100)
random_integer =  random.randint (b=100, a=1)


In python if the syntax of a method or function is function_name(a,b), if you are not changing the order(sequence) of the arguments, you can directly call with the arguments without mentioning parameters' name.
random_integer =  random.randint ( 1, 100 )

If you are not sure about the order or sequence of the parameters, then the parameter name and argument should be separated by an = sign.
# I 've mentioned a and b as I don't know which comes first between a and b
# note: I've changed the order a and b still you get proper result


random_integer =  random.randint ( b= 100, a= 1 ) 


Fixes:
a = 1
b = 100
random_integer = random.randint(a, b)

random_integer = random.randint(a=1, b=100)

Your code didn't work as it didn't use proper syntax.
random.randint(a, b)

will generate a random number between a and b inclusive.
